# Combobox component doesnt iterate through its items correctly on keypress Delphi 10.2

Tags: delphi, combobox

On occasions I have found that the combo box doesn't appear to function/update correctly in Delphi 10.2.

I have created a simple form with a single combobox on it.  Using the items property the combobox has the following properties, a,b,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,d,e.

If once the form opens I tap the c key I cannot guarantee that the combobox will cycle through the c items in order, sometimes it sticks on the same item, sometimes it misses an item out.

Anybody else experienced this or has any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I see the same, but why not use the arrow down key, which works fine?

Comment: THis is just a mock up of an application created for a customer where the combobox is tab order 1 on a form and the key press that used to work in Delphi 3 is no longer guaranteed to.  This behaviour affects their workflow and they raised it with us.  The down key also exhibits the same behaviour for me.

Comment: You mean that the down key works, right?. If you want the `c` key to mean the same thing as the down key, you would have to handle a key event.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the down arrow also iterates through incorrectly.

Comment: It works for me in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo. I suggest you make a minimal example and add that to your question.

Comment: Unable to reproduce this problem. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this.  The autocomplete setting on the combobox was set to true, once set to false the combobox behaves correctly and cycles through all items as expected.